# Excel VBA: Generate Footer in WordFile

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, footer

I built an Excel-File with VBA, where you can generate Directories and put the correct Documents (Word- and Excel-Files) right into the correct Directory. So when you execute the Code(in Excel), you first have to choose your Root-Destination and then all Directories are created. After that, it get's Worddocuments from a Templatefolder, fills the Textmarks with Data from Excel and saves the file. This is working great, also thanks to this community.

But now the Problem: I don't get it to work, to fill in the new filename in the footer of the word-document.

This is the code for the complete function for now:

```
    Public Function Txtmkr_SDD()


    Dim appWord             As Object 'Word-Instance
    Dim wdDoc               As Object 'Word-Document
    Dim wdRngE              As Object 'Word-Range 1
    Dim wdRngR              As Object 'Word-Range 2
    Dim wdRngC              As Object 'Word-Range 3
    Dim wdRngCN             As Object 'Word-Range 4

    Dim wks                 As Worksheet 'Excel-Worksheet
    Dim AdresseCE           As String
    Dim neueAdresseCE       As Long
    Dim Processname1        As String
    Dim Processname2        As String
    Dim Version             As String

    '*** Word start ***
    Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    '*** opens File ***
   Set wdDoc = appWord.Documents.Add(Template:=Worksheets("StartPage").Cells(48, 4) & "\Document_Templates\SDD_Template.dotx", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0)

    '*** Word visible ***
    appWord.Visible = True

    '*** just in case Document is protected ***
    'doc.Unprotect

    '*** Jump to Textmarker in Word ***
    '*** Check of existence ***
    '*** Take Value from "CopyData" Cell "B1" and insert Textmarker ***
    If wdDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("Processname1") Then
        With wdDoc.Bookmarks("Processname1")
            Set wdRngE = .Range
            wdRngE.Text = Worksheets("CopyData").Cells(1, 2).Value
            wdDoc.Bookmarks.Add "Processname1", wdRngE
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Missing Link [Processname1]."
    End If

      '*** Take Value from "CopyData" Cell "B2" and insert Textmarker ***
    If wdDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("Processname2") Then
        With wdDoc.Bookmarks("Processname2")
            Set wdRngE = .Range
            wdRngE.Text = Worksheets("CopyData").Cells(2, 2).Value
            wdDoc.Bookmarks.Add "Processname2", wdRngE
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Missing Link [Processname2]."
    End If


      If wdDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("Version") Then
        With wdDoc.Bookmarks("Version")
            Set wdRngE = .Range
            wdRngE.Text = Worksheets("CopyData").Cells(3, 2).Value
            wdDoc.Bookmarks.Add "Version", wdRngE
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Missing Link [Version]."
    End If


          If wdDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("Create_Date") Then
        With wdDoc.Bookmarks("Create_Date")
            Set wdRngE = .Range
            wdRngE.Text = Worksheets("CopyData").Cells(4, 2).Value
            wdDoc.Bookmarks.Add "Create_Date", wdRngE
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Missing Link [Create_Date]."
    End If


              If wdDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("Author") Then
        With wdDoc.Bookmarks("Author")
            Set wdRngE = .Range
            wdRngE.Text = Worksheets("CopyData").Cells(6, 2).Value
            wdDoc.Bookmarks.Add "Author", wdRngE
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Missing Link [Author]."
    End If


   '*** Set Time_Date and SDD Path ***
    Dim time_date As String
    time_date = Format(Date, "yyyy_mm_dd")
    Dim SDD As String

    '*** Define SDD as RegularPath ***
    SDD = (time_date & "_" & Worksheets("CopyData").Cells(1, 2).Value & "_" & Worksheets("CopyData").Cells(21, 2).Value & "_" & Worksheets("Helper#3").Cells(3, 2).Value & "_" & "V" & Worksheets("CopyData").Cells(3, 2).Value & ".docx")

    '*** Dim wdApp As Word.Application ***
    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    '*** Set up SavePath & Filename ***
    appWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Worksheets("Variables").Cells(3, 8).Value & "\" & (Worksheets("Setup#2_DirectoryList").Cells(1, 1)) & "\" & Worksheets("Setup#2_DirectoryList").Cells(3, 3).Value & "\" & Worksheets("Setup#2_DirectoryList").Cells(14, 21).Value & "\" & SDD

    '*** Word quit ***
    appWord.ActiveDocument.Close
    appWord.Quit

    '*** disable Variables ***
    Set wdRngE = Nothing
    Set wdRngR = Nothing
    Set wdRngC = Nothing
    Set wdRngCN = Nothing
    Set wdRng = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set appWord = Nothing
    Set sFolder = Nothing

End Function
```

Would be great if anyone could help me :-)

Comment: Could you not just have the file name in the footer in your template?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put a FILENAME field in the template's footer. That way, you don't need code to do the same thing. Instead, all you need do (after saving the file) is use:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument
  .Fields.Update
  .PrintPreview
  .ClosePrintPreview
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

then re-save to make the field update 'stick'.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **marcroprod** the issue is resolved.
For everyone with similar problems, here's the complete code now:

```
Public Function Txtmkr_SDD()


    Dim appWord             As Object 'Word-Instance
    Dim wdDoc               As Object 'Word-Document
    Dim wdRngE              As Object 'Word-Range 1
    Dim wdRngR              As Object 'Word-Range 2
    Dim wdRngC              As Object 'Word-Range 3
    Dim wdRngCN             As Object 'Word-Range 4

    Dim wks                 As Worksheet 'Excel-Worksheet
    Dim AdresseCE           As String
    Dim neueAdresseCE       As Long
    Dim Processname1        As String
    Dim Processname2        As String
    Dim Version             As String

    '*** Word start ***
    Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    '*** opens File ***
   Set wdDoc = appWord.Documents.Add(Template:=Worksheets("StartPage").Cells(48, 4) & "\Document_Templates\SDD_Template.dotx", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0)

    '*** Word visible ***
    appWord.Visible = True

    '*** just in case Document is protected ***
    'doc.Unprotect

    '*** Jump to Textmarker in Word ***
    '*** Check of existence ***
    '*** Take Value from "CopyData" Cell "B1" and insert Textmarker ***
    If wdDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("Processname1") Then
        With wdDoc.Bookmarks("Processname1")
            Set wdRngE = .Range
            wdRngE.Text = Worksheets("CopyData").Cells(1, 2).Value
            wdDoc.Bookmarks.Add "Processname1", wdRngE
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Missing Link [Processname1]."
    End If

      '*** Take Value from "CopyData" Cell "B2" and insert Textmarker ***
    If wdDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("Processname2") Then
        With wdDoc.Bookmarks("Processname2")
            Set wdRngE = .Range
            wdRngE.Text = Worksheets("CopyData").Cells(2, 2).Value
            wdDoc.Bookmarks.Add "Processname2", wdRngE
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Missing Link [Processname2]."
    End If


      If wdDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("Version") Then
        With wdDoc.Bookmarks("Version")
            Set wdRngE = .Range
            wdRngE.Text = Worksheets("CopyData").Cells(3, 2).Value
            wdDoc.Bookmarks.Add "Version", wdRngE
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Missing Link [Version]."
    End If


          If wdDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("Create_Date") Then
        With wdDoc.Bookmarks("Create_Date")
            Set wdRngE = .Range
            wdRngE.Text = Worksheets("CopyData").Cells(4, 2).Value
            wdDoc.Bookmarks.Add "Create_Date", wdRngE
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Missing Link [Create_Date]."
    End If


              If wdDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("Author") Then
        With wdDoc.Bookmarks("Author")
            Set wdRngE = .Range
            wdRngE.Text = Worksheets("CopyData").Cells(6, 2).Value
            wdDoc.Bookmarks.Add "Author", wdRngE
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Missing Link [Author]."
    End If


   '*** Set Time_Date and SDD Path ***
    Dim time_date As String
    time_date = Format(Date, "yyyy_mm_dd")
    Dim SDD As String

    '*** Define SDD as RegularPath ***
    SDD = (time_date & "_" & Worksheets("CopyData").Cells(1, 2).Value & "_" & Worksheets("CopyData").Cells(21, 2).Value & "_" & Worksheets("Helper#3").Cells(3, 2).Value & "_" & "V" & Worksheets("CopyData").Cells(3, 2).Value & ".docx")

    '*** Dim wdApp As Word.Application ***
    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    '*** Set up SavePath & Filename ***
    appWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Worksheets("Variables").Cells(3, 8).Value & "\" & (Worksheets("Setup#2_DirectoryList").Cells(1, 1)) & "\" & Worksheets("Setup#2_DirectoryList").Cells(3, 3).Value & "\" & Worksheets("Setup#2_DirectoryList").Cells(14, 21).Value & "\" & SDD

    '*** Updating the Footer of the Document ***
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With appWord.ActiveDocument
        .Fields.Update
        .PrintPreview
        .ClosePrintPreview
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    appWord.ActiveDocument.Save


    '*** Word quit ***
    appWord.ActiveDocument.Close
    appWord.Quit

    '*** disable Variables ***
    Set wdRngE = Nothing
    Set wdRngR = Nothing
    Set wdRngC = Nothing
    Set wdRngCN = Nothing
    Set wdRng = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set appWord = Nothing
    Set sFolder = Nothing

End Function
```